# JPA- ManyToMany relation the delete operation removes all entities from secondary table

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring data JPA and postgres database.
I have two entities namely group and user. 
I have created repository using Spring's CrudRepository inteface.

```
@Entity
public class Group { 
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name="group_user_bridge", 
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="joinTbl_groupid", referencedColumnName="groupid"), 
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="joinTbl_agentid", referencedColumnName="userid")
        )
private Set<User> users;
....
}
```

class User

```
@Entity
public class User {

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="users",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Group> groups;
.....
 }
```

Repository.save : Works fine.

```
  @Test
  public void addGroup(){
        Group hg = new Group();

        User h1 = new User();
        User h2 = new User();
        some setters for user entity object

        hg.setName("testGroup");
        ... some setters for groups

        HashSet<User> groupMembers = new HashSet<User>();
        groupMembers.add(h2);
        groupMembers.add(h1);
        hg.setGroupMembers(groupMembers);

        hg = groupRepository.save(hg);
```

Question

When I delete the group using groupRepository.delete(groupEntity), it deletes the group, the association of group **and users** from join table.
but it also deletes the users from user table. In fact the **users records should not get deleted**.

**How to prevent user deletion here?**

I am using @SQLDelete annotation for soft deleting the group and user records. but I am not able to achieve the same for the join table records. **The records in the join table gets hard deleted from the  table which I want to prevent.**

**How can we prevent hard delete of the join table records?**

Answer (score 0):

You currently to have this annotation in the `User` and `Group` classes:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
```

The [Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/metamodel/binding/CascadeType.html) indicate that this will cause cascading of the following operations: `save, delete, update, evict, lock, replicate, merge, persist`

So it makes sense that when you delete the `Group` instance, the delete cascades to the `User` instances.

Consider changing the annotation to something like:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
```

Or whatever is appropriate for your application.

Optionally, you can remove the `User` instances from the `Group` prior to deleting the `Group`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Will check the SAVE_UPDATE and check. I was considering a scenario where user can be moved across the group so if once group is deleted the users should remain intact.